# Overwrite Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp

Tags: magento-1, overrides, paypal, model, paypal-express

I want to **overwrite `Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp` in my custom_module**. 
For this, I have follow following steps but after that also core file is calling.

config.xml

```
 <models>
     <paypal>
       <rewrite>
          <api_nvp>Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Api_Nvp</api_nvp>
      </rewrite>
    </paypal>
</models>
```

Nvp.php

```
class Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Api_Nvp extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp
{
    <!-- Code -->
}
```

I have cleared cache, session, logs. But after that also my file is not called.

Comment: please check complier]

Comment: compiler is not enabled.

Comment: check class name by echo get_class(Mage::getModel('paypal/api_nvp')) is  Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Api_Nvp. If it will given value  Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Api_Nvp then the rewrite is proper

Comment: core file is called :(

Comment: Could you post the full `config.xml` fragment? The `<models/>` node should be inside `<config><global>...`

Comment: Turn on the debug mode and check logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code definitely looks ok.

As the full `config.xml` file is missing here is what it should look like to ensure your rewrite works:

`app/code/local/Mycompany/Modulename/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Modulename>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Mycompany_Modulename>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <models>  
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <api_nvp>Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Api_Nvp</api_nvp>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </models>
    </global> 
</config>
```

Then you need to you ensure the path to your custom model is right, it should be `app/code/local/Mycompany/Modulename/Model/Api/Nvp.php`

Once you're done with that don't forget to:

- recompile
- flush the cache